# Putting animated text in the background with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've found other examples of text in the background but not animated. [I want it to be positioned like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFwo5.png)

Here's what I'm working with. https://jsfiddle.net/3esj55rb

```css
.marquee {
    color: #333;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    font: 50px 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    width: 450px;
    margin: 2em auto
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 25s linear infinite;
}
.marquee:hover {
    color: #F65314;
    animation-play-state: paused
}
@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        text-indent: 27.5em
    }
    100% {
        text-indent: -105em
    }
}

/* Make it pretty */

.microsoft {
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    font: 50px 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

/* ::before was :before before ::before was ::before - kthx */

.microsoft:before,
.microsoft::before {
    z-index: 2;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -1em;
    left: -1em;
    width: .5em;
    height: .5em;
    box-shadow: 1.0em 1.25em 0 #F65314, 1.6em 1.25em 0 #7CBB00, 1.0em 1.85em 0 #00A1F1, 1.6em 1.85em 0 #FFBB00;
}

.microsoft:after,
.microsoft::after {
    z-index: 1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, white 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}

/* Style the links */

.vanity {
    color: #333;
    text-align: left;
    font: 20px 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

.vanity a,
.microsoft a {
    color: #1570A6;
    transition: color .5s;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.vanity a:hover,
.microsoft a:hover {
    color: #F65314;
}

.text {
    color: #333;
    text-align: left;
    font: 20px 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
.topText {
    color: #333;
    text-align: left;
    font: 20px 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<p class="topText">
    Boston, city, capital of the commonwealth of Massachusetts, 
    and seat of Suffolk county, in the northeastern United States. 
    It lies on Massachusetts Bay, an arm of the Atlantic Ocean. 
    The city proper has an unusually small area for a major city,
    and more than one-fourth of the total—including part of the 
    Charles River, Boston Harbor, and a portion of the Atlantic—is water.
    Area city, 46 square miles (119 square km).
</p>
<p class="marquee"> Visit Boston. This text should be in the background</p>
<p class="text"> 
    The area, the people, and the institutions within its political 
    boundaries can only begin to define the essence of Boston. Its 
    nickname “Beantown” has its origin in colonial times, when Boston, 
    as a stop on a major trade route with the West Indies, had a steady 
    supply of molasses from the Caribbean, thus leading to the creation 
    of a popular dish that became known as Boston baked beans (beans 
    baked in molasses).
</p>
<p class="vanity">
    Follow us on twitter
    <a href="https://twitter.com/boston">@boston</a> to know more.
</p>
<p class="vanity">
    Test test
    <a href="boston.gov">click here for website</a> or our state's <a href="mass.gov"> mass.gov </a>
</p>
```

Comment: How does your text need to be animated? You’ll probably need absolute positioning of some sort and add a css animation. However, as your question currently stands it’s a little unclear.

Comment: It's already animated like in the jfiddle. I just can't determine how to have it be under other another text box like in the sample image.

Comment: Ah, I do apologise, I’m on mobile which might be why I can’t see the animation. Have you tried wrapping the animated text in an absolutely positioned container? You can set the z index on this to ensure it’s below anything else.

Comment: Thank you,  doing those two things worked. I'll post the updated snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Added z index and made position relative to the container.

```
.marquee {
    color: #333;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    font: 50px 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 2em auto
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;

    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    width: 450px;
    top: 15%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the use of CSS you can define @keyframes so that you can create different positions, sizes, angels and properties of an object.

for your reference:

```
@keyframes example {
  0%   {background-color: red;}
  25%  {background-color: yellow;}
  50%  {background-color: blue;}
  100% {background-color: green;}
}
```

Here you can find the resources:https://css-tricks.com/css-techniques-and-effects-for-knockout-text/

Answer (score -1):

### Short answer

You have to play with position (relative / absolute along with top). Beware of children ordering. Also, when you need to stop the animation when hovering, make sure you are putting the `:hover` listener to the proper tag.

### Long answer

For the sake of playing with position, I came up with a solution. However, this solution requires text duplication.

The idea is as follows:

- A `container` will contain three children
- The first child is the first text. It is invisible and its purpose is to fix the `container` height
- The second child is the sliding text. With a `position: absolute`, it has to vertically align its content via a subcontainer.
- The third child is the displayed text with an absolute position as well

I expanded the original text to ensure that my marquee is properly vertically aligned.

- **Cons**

  - Text is displayed twice
  - a lot of CSS classes & container but it is always like this, isn't it?
- **Pros**

  - You can put whatever you want in the `.marquee__content`, not only a `p` but also some `h2` or `h3` or some picture, it should all slide. the `.marquee *{...}` style ensure that all children do not wrap text
  - CSS clearer separation: which div is what

Finally the code:

```css
/* ========== Container ========== */


/* cosmetic only */

body {
  background-color: #cacaca;
}

.container {
  /* Required for playing with positions ! */
  position: relative;
  /* irrelevant: cosmetic only */
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
}


/* ========== Text =============== */


/* define all text size so that height fixer can
         have the appropriate height */

.text {
  /* to ensure both box__text have same height */
  font-size: 20px;
  /* cosmetic only */
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* this hack requires an invisible box__text to set
         parent div height */

.text--height-fixer {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.text--shown {
  position: absolute;
  /* move to top of parent */
  top: 0;
  /* take parent width / height */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* ========== Marquee ============ */

.marquee {
  position: absolute;
  /* move to top of parent */
  top: 0;
  /* take parent width / height */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* hide x overflow for the slide effect */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* vertically align content. I chose display: flex as
        I am lazy but this is not the core of the question */
  display: flex;
  /* cosmetic only */
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0.6;
}


/* force one line layout for all children, not only <p> */

.marquee * {
  /* remove line break */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* remove all default margin */
  margin: auto;
}


/* to match the provided picture */

.marquee .boston {
  color: lightblue;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
}

.marquee__content {
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}


/* this is the tricky part: the "hover" event should not be listened
        on marquee but on the container */

.container:hover .marquee__content {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.container:hover .marquee .boston {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!-- container to manage all positions. Children order matters !-->
<div class="container">
  <!-- relative must be first -->
  <div class="text text--height-fixer">
    <p>
      The area, the people, and the institutions within its political boundaries can only begin to define the essence of Boston. Its nickname “Beantown” has its origin in colonial times, when Boston, as a stop on a major trade route with the West Indies, had
      a steady supply of molasses from the Caribbean, thus leading to the creation of a popular dish that became known as Boston baked beans (beans baked in molasses). The area, the people, and the institutions within its political boundaries can only
      begin to define the essence of Boston. Its nickname “Beantown” has its origin in colonial times, when Boston, as a stop on a major trade route with the West Indies, had a steady supply of molasses from the Caribbean, thus leading to the creation
      of a popular dish that became known as Boston baked beans (beans baked in molasses).
    </p>
  </div>

  <!-- marquee should be declared before text so that it appears below without z-index -->
  <div class="marquee">
    <div class="marquee__content">
      <p class="boston">
        Visit Boston. This text should be in the background
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="text text--shown">
    <p>
      The area, the people, and the institutions within its political boundaries can only begin to define the essence of Boston. Its nickname “Beantown” has its origin in colonial times, when Boston, as a stop on a major trade route with the West Indies, had
      a steady supply of molasses from the Caribbean, thus leading to the creation of a popular dish that became known as Boston baked beans (beans baked in molasses). The area, the people, and the institutions within its political boundaries can only
      begin to define the essence of Boston. Its nickname “Beantown” has its origin in colonial times, when Boston, as a stop on a major trade route with the West Indies, had a steady supply of molasses from the Caribbean, thus leading to the creation
      of a popular dish that became known as Boston baked beans (beans baked in molasses).
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone has a better solution which allows any *marquee* content (not limited to a single `p`), feel free to share!